# LSTM neural network test to predict SPY prices giving me this error after training

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow, keras

Error is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myname/PycharmProjects/LSTM1P/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3080, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 101, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 4554, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 4562, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Open'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myname/PycharmProjects/LSTM1P/matplottest.py", line 47, in <module>
    dataset_total = pd.concat((dataset_train['Open'], dataset_test['Open']), axis = 0)
  File "/Users/myname/PycharmProjects/LSTM1P/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3024, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "/Users/myname/PycharmProjects/LSTM1P/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3082, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'Open'
```

My Code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import keras

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/khammerberg53/MLPROJ1/main/SP500.csv'
dataset_train = pd.read_csv(url)
training_set = dataset_train.iloc[:, 1:2].values

dataset_train.head()
print(dataset_train.head())

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
sc = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
training_set_scaled = sc.fit_transform(training_set)

X_train = []
y_train = []
for i in range(60, 2000):
    X_train.append(training_set_scaled[i-60:i, 0])
    y_train.append(training_set_scaled[i, 0])
X_train, y_train = np.array(X_train), np.array(y_train)
X_train = np.reshape(X_train, (X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 1))

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers import Dense

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=50,return_sequences=True,input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], 1)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units=50,return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units=50,return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(units=50))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(units=1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mean_squared_error')
model.fit(X_train,y_train,epochs=100,batch_size=32)

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/khammerberg53/MLPROJ1/main/SP500%20test%20setcsv.csv'
dataset_train = pd.read_csv(url)
training_set = dataset_train.iloc[:, 1:2].values

dataset_total = pd.concat((dataset_train['Open'], dataset_test['Open']), axis = 0)
inputs = dataset_total[len(dataset_total) - len(dataset_test) - 60:].values
inputs = inputs.reshape(-1,1)
inputs = sc.transform(inputs)
X_test = []
for i in range(3, 100):
    X_test.append(inputs[i-60:i, 0])
X_test = np.array(X_test)
X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1], 1))
predicted_stock_price = model.predict(X_test)
predicted_stock_price = sc.inverse_transform(predicted_stock_price)

plt.plot(real_stock_price, color = 'black', label = 'TATA Stock Price')
plt.plot(predicted_stock_price, color = 'green', label = 'Predicted TATA Stock Price')
plt.title('TATA Stock Price Prediction')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('TATA Stock Price')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

print(plt.show())
```

Not sure what's going on....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check you train dataset, there is no `Open` column there, so `dataset_train['Open']` fails:

```
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/khammerberg53/MLPROJ1/main/SP500%20test%20setcsv.csv'
dataset_train = pd.read_csv(url)
dataset_train.head()
```

Output:

```
         Date   Value
0  1994-09-02  470.99
1  1994-09-09  468.18
2  1994-09-16  471.19
3  1994-09-23  459.67
4  1994-09-30  462.71
```

Maybe you want to use `dataset_train['Value']` instead